# NFC popup window

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to work on a school project with the idea likewise to the NFC restaurant, with reference to the customerin nfc solution [[video here]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw22iFwDeDQ) where they were tapping the phone with the nfc tag, and it pops up a window with various links, like menu and other options.

I basically have two questions:

1. In the video at 1:22 mark, is the popup window an android app or is that a webpage, or something else?
2. Is there any recommendation to make it secure such that when a customer leaves the restaurant, he/she does not have the option to call for bill or server, only the option to view the menu and coupon?

Can anyone please provide some advice? Thanks.